# Partitioning increases CPU usage in mariadb

Tags: mysql, innodb, mariadb, partitioning, mariadb-10.2

I'm using mariadb 10.2, and I had a table with a structure similar to the one below, currently with 15gb, where I insert a few thousand records per minute all the time, each batch for a specific account (AccountId1).

```
AccountId1 bigint PK,
AccountId2 bigint PK,
ActionType int,
ActionDate timestamp
```

Looking at the process list, multiple inserts were waiting in line for this table, and they were always one insert running at a time, so I decided to partition this table by hash on the AccountId1, and created 32 partitions.

The inserts now jumped from 1 or 2 a second to 8 during peak times, and that worked great. The issue is that the CPU usage jumped from 15% to 40% after the change, and even stopping the insert process completely for a few hours, the CPU won't go down.

[image: cpu usage before and after partitioning]

There are a few places where we select from this table that could span all partitions, but these are processes that run every few hours and don't take that long. Other frequent queries always use the `AccountId1` field and are indeed querying a single partition by looking at the query plan.

Is there any overhead associated with partitioning, even if no sql is touching that table? What could be the reason for this increase in CPU?

Note: there are around 2000 concurrent connections at any time, but the # of connections before and after the partitioning were the same.

Comment: We really need to see `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to address the CPU issue.  Are the `INSERTs` done one row at a time?  Or batched in some way?

Comment: And, is each connection for only one AccountID1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## OVERHEAD

What needs to be understood is a partitioned table's physical implementation.

For example, in my old post (`Aug 31, 2014` : [How does subpartitioning actually work and what physical files are created?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75380/how-does-subpartitioning-actually-work-and-what-physical-files-are-created/75387#75387)), I displayed what a partitioned table looks like:

```
C:\>cd \MySQL_5.6.15\data\test

C:\MySQL_5.6.15\data\test>dir nums_comp*
 Volume in drive C is TI10665200H
 Volume Serial Number is A273-2EFF

 Directory of C:\MySQL_5.6.15\data\test

08/31/2014  04:09 PM            98,304 nums_composite#p#p0#sp#p0sp0.ibd
08/31/2014  04:09 PM            98,304 nums_composite#p#p0#sp#p0sp1.ibd
08/31/2014  04:09 PM            98,304 nums_composite#p#p1#sp#p1sp0.ibd
08/31/2014  04:09 PM            98,304 nums_composite#p#p1#sp#p1sp1.ibd
08/31/2014  04:09 PM            98,304 nums_composite#p#p2#sp#p2sp0.ibd
08/31/2014  04:09 PM            98,304 nums_composite#p#p2#sp#p2sp1.ibd
08/31/2014  04:09 PM             8,594 nums_composite.frm
08/31/2014  04:09 PM                96 nums_composite.par
               8 File(s)        598,514 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  686,691,409,920 bytes free

C:\MySQL_5.6.15\data\test>
```

I have another example in `Feb 16, 2015` : [MySQL Create Table with Partition Slow on server machine](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/91958/mysql-create-table-with-partition-slow-on-server-machine/92018#92018)

Each partition is treated as a separate InnoDB table with a distinct tablespace.

What overhead exists ?

- Memory Usage for the Information Schema ([Adding new tables -- memory usage increases](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/63591/adding-new-tables-memory-usage-increases/63593#63593))
- Index Stats Separated By Partition ([Do I need to index a key that I partition by?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25554/do-i-need-to-index-a-key-that-i-partition-by/25579#25579))
- Open File Handles (In your case, 33 [1 File Handle for Each `.ibd` file, 1 for `.frm`])

While these things help explain the overhead, you must still be wondering where the CPU activity is coming from ???

## CPU

There will still be some CPU activity based on the open file handles. How ?

The option innodb_open_files places a limit on the number of open file handles against all InnoDB tables through the MySQL Instance.

If table info needs to be examined by monitoring software, more queries make more CPU.

If there are any queries that do not access disk (such as `SHOW PROCESSLIST;` or `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;`) or reads from INFORMATION_SCHEMA, more CPU. (See my old ServerFault post from `2011-08-10` [1 billion mysql queries in 24 days? Can something be wrong?](https://serverfault.com/questions/299694/1-billion-mysql-queries-in-24-days-can-something-be-wrong/299806#299806))

Opening and closing files handles to access certain tables and read 16K pages into the InnoDB Buffer or marking pages in the InnoDB Buffer Pool as old.

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look at these points and see what I can do.

Comment: After looking into the variables and doing some math, I still though there was no reason for such a high increase. So I decided to reboot the instance, and things went back to normal. It may be a bug, I don't know, but looks like something is not cleaning up something inside mariadb.

Comment: Additional information request, please. 
RAM on your Host server 
current complete my.cnf-ini 
Text results of: 
A) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; 
B) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
C) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
Optional very helpful information, if available includes -
htop   OR  top for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -x when system is busy for an idea of IOPS by device, 
df -h  for a linux/unix free space list by device, 
free -m  for a linux/unix free memory report, 
complete MySQLTuner.com  report if readily available.

Comment: @natan  Please consider posting the information requested Apr 2 at 22:25.  Thanks

Comment: I appreciate the attempt to find the root cause, but we've already upgraded the instance, so the current values won't match what we had before. and I don't have access to the OS to get some of the requested stats. All I can say it was a 48 CPU / 192Gb RAM RDS instance on AWS managed by them. There were 15Gb of free RAM available at the time, and 3Tb of disk available.

Comment: @natan Even with upgraded instance, posting information requested Apr 2 will likely find performance improvements for your consideration.